# update first 10 rows with one value and next 10 with another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table members

```
members

id      data
1         a
2         a
3         a
4         b
5         b
6         b
7         b
```

Here , I want the 1st 3 id's to be updated to a, next 3 id's to b and next 3 to a and so on. Please help me to do it in sql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (Assuming SQL Server 2005+):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            id2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) - 1
    FROM YourTable
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            id2/3%2 N
    FROM CTE1
)
UPDATE CTE2
SET data = CASE WHEN N = 0 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END;

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d223/2) with a demo.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following statements:

```
update members set data = 'a' where ((id-1)/3)%2 = 0;
update members set data = 'b' where ((id-1)/3)%2 = 1;
```

Comment: Your query does not work for me. What is div ? I tried this - `select * from members where (id / 3) % 2 = 0;` and I get the wrong rows.

Comment: + 1, Good one. Though `id div 3` actually should be `id / 3`. This also assumes that `id` is an `INT`, and always sequentially numbered (even though that could be the case)

Comment: @Lamak - This query gives the wrong results. Only first two rows get a, next three get b, next two get a...etc.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Yeah, it should be `((id-1)/3)%2`, but the idea is generally ok.

Comment: it depends on which database server you are using. The statements are tested on mysql, but if you are using the other database, the grammar could be different. Please check the doc of your database and modify the statements.

Comment: @Hai Well, the question is tagged with SQL Server, so you should assume that the answer must be valid for that RDBMS. Anyway, it's not a big deal and someone else edited your answer so it's valid now (but in the future you might want to be more careful)

Comment: @Lamak ah.. ok, didn't notice the tag, it's my first answer, didn't have such experience. Thank you to remind me of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id into #temp from members order by id
 declare @i int = 'a'
 While Exists (select * from #temp)
 begin
 update members 
 set data = @i
 where id in (select top 1 id from #temp order by id)
 if(@i = 'a')
    set @i = 'b';
 else
   set @i ='a'
 delete from #temp where id in (select top 1 id from #temp order by id)
end

select * from members
```

above queries are great,small and precise,but if u r looking for anything that's simple/very easy this should work :)